# How to make Apps support on Android 9

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have to build an apps, it support until android 9
with the gradle setting look like

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sdept.company.starmobile"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 6

    versionName "1.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

with above setting it running well when app-debug version, but when I try to upload in Google Play, google play required me to change min targetSDKVersion to 28. so I change it to this

```
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sdept.company.starmobile"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 6

    versionName "1.6"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.2.4'
compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.0.4'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
//    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
// JSON Parsing
//    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
//    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
//    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:11.0.4'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

it successfull when uppload on playstore but the application cannot running on android 9, where is the part of code i have to change so that can running well in Android 9 (Pie)

Comment: compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.0"

Comment: correct compileSdkVersion and build tools version too

Comment: @Athira how about dependencies i wrote, it need to change too?

Comment: Yes. If you find issues finding correct versions go to Files->Project Structure -> app ->dependencies -> Library dependency-> choose library

Answer (score 0):

Change ur configuration like following 
       `buildToolsVersion = "21.0.1"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 27
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"`

Comment: how about dependencies,, should it change?

Answer (score 0):

**First**, you need to setup your **app** `build.gradle` to support Android 9, which is API Level 28, by targeting to API Level 28. So, change your build.gradle to something like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 28
  buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"


  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 28

     ...
  }

  ...

}

...

dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
}
```

**Second**, ensure that you're using https instead http. Please visit my previous answer for details:
[Internet permission not working in oreo and pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074899/internet-permission-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie/55074969#55074969)

Please visit [Behavior changes: apps targeting API level 28+](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-28)  for details about the changes in API Level 28+.