# Android App doesn't have internet connection - No Permissions required

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-permissions

Well, I have built an app to store values on a remote database. It works!! I didn't use an emulator for testing instead I used my own phone. Now the problem is that on my phone, it works perfectly...no issues but when I installed it on another phone, the app doesn't connect to the internet.
I have included internet permission in android manifest.xml.

I have tried these but didn't work:

1. Building apk and installing in the new phone.
2. Compiling directly to the new phone.
3. Sending the apk from old phone to new phone via shareit.
4. Creating a signed apk and installing.
5. Checked via wifi and mobile data (NOTE: BOTH WIFI AND MOBILE DATA WORKS IN OLD PHONE).
6. Checked android compatibility: supports up to android 10.

*I added error messages for try...catch blocks in form of toasts for the user to know what's the issue. and the catch exception for no internet returns connection problem. I'm getting that error message.

As I researched, I got to know that internet permission is categorized as normal permission which is not prompted to the user upon installation.

I built a second dummy app: Same issue with it... compiled directly to new phone but didn't work...it works in old phone...

Old phone: Samsung J7 Prime with Android 8.1
New Phone: Samsung J7 Pro with Android 9

Any idea or suggestion will be gladly helpful... Thank you!

Comment: Please post the permissions you are declaring in manifest.

Comment: Some remote databases have debug and release access to the data, check for that as well.

Comment: You can check if this is your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074899/internet-permission-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie

Comment: @SABANTO it's cannot be a connection problem!! because the same app works in my old phone... i'm getting issues only with my new phone

Comment: @littlebear333 thanks...I'll try with https and will update if it works

Comment: @Varun the only permission i declared is: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: @littlebear333 the https which was in the other thread didn't work either

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in android 9 and above you have to set network Security Config
first of all in res package create xml package and in xml package create new xml resource file with network_security_config name

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" />
 </network-security-config>
```

then in manifest in

```
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config

it can help you

Answer (score 1):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: i already included that in my android manifest... you didn't understand the question i guess...the app works in one phone....but the same thing doesn't work in another

Comment: Did you check if the permission is provided for the app? Check it through Apps section of your device settings.

Comment: @CharanM yes in all permissions: it's written full network access

Answer (score 0):

Use debug APK instead of signed APK

Comment: when you compile a project at first, you get the debug apk... soo it's obvious that it has been tried. Read it again, the app works in my old phone but not in the new one...with no changes made

Answer (score 0):

please add permission on Manifest to give a permission of permission.INTERNET

Comment: Please read the post again: i already included the permission: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />