# Android App Permission Internet set in Manifest but not work

Tags: android, permissions

i need the permission Internet in my Android App.

Here my Manifest-File:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.medshoppro">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:name=".application.GlobalDataStore"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".activities.Test"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MedShopPro"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

But if i start my App on my Phone (Pixel 4 XL) i can´t use the Internet. And i can´t give my App the permission over App-Details->Permissions.

What is missing or wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found my mistake. I used **httpclient** but in version O and P i have to use **HttpsURLConnection**.

[Internet permission not working in oreo and pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55074899/internet-permission-not-working-in-oreo-and-pie)